# How to edit material of grease pencil stroke across all keyframes?

Tags: animation, materials, edit-mode, grease-pencil, 2d

I'm very new to Blender and have a simple question.

I have an animated Grease Pencil stroke and would like to edit its color. I don't want it to be changing colors in the animation, I just want to edit the material across all keyframes. Even when I select all relevant keyframes for that stroke, the color change only applies to the current keyframe. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: that's weird, I get the opposite behaviour, when I change the stroke colour in the material tab it changes all frames

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same issue and found how to solve it.

1. Select all the points of your Grease pencil object in *Edit Mode*
2. Select not only all the keyframes but the animation layer in the [`Dope Sheet Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/dope_sheet/grease_pencil.html)
3. At the top panel turn on multiframe
4. Now you can apply a new material to all the keyframes in your animation.